# Tabulate All Folder Contents Recursively

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

## Background

I am comparing a local and a OneDrive version of the same drive, in order to identify discrepancies in the sync.  There are nearly 20,000 files in total, among deeply nested folders.

I have tried other solutions, but I prefer to keep everything in Excel, for reasons too numerous to detail here.  As such, I am using PowerQuery to list the contents of each drive, and I will then use various [`Table.*Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-join)s to compare those contents.

## Problem

Unfortunately, no native option meets my needs.  While [`Folder.Files()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/folder-files) does list all *files* recursively, it fails to include the *folders*.  By contrast, [`Folder.Contents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/folder-contents) does include the folders, but it fails to list the contents *recursively*—rather, it shows only the "first level".

As such, I created the custom function `Folder_FullContents()`, to *recursively* list both files *and* folders:

```m
let Folder_FullContents = (
    path as text,
    optional options as nullable record
) as any =>
    let
        contents = Folder.Contents(path, options),
        subfolders = Table.AddColumn(
            Table.SelectRows(contents, each [Attributes][Directory]),
            "File Path",
            each Text.Combine({[Folder Path], [Name]}),
            type text
        )[File Path],
        result = Table.Combine(List.Combine({{contents},
            List.Transform(subfolders, Folder_FullContents)
        }))
    in result
in Folder_FullContents
```

While **`Folder_FullContents()` does *technically* work, it is prohibitively *slow*** for 20,000 files.

## Question

Is there a reliable solution in PowerQuery M, that

1. *recursively* lists
2. all files *and* folders beneath a directory, with
3. performance no worse than `.Files()` or `.Contents()` at scale?

### Note

There are some empty folders on these drives.  As such, it is insufficient to simply append the [`.Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-distinct) set of `[Folder Path]`s from `Folder.Files()`, to the dataset of the files themselves.
Doing so would omit the empty folders, which do not appear in any *file*paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffering usually solves problems like this. I have tried the following which returns 121k rows in about 6 seconds.

```
let Folder_FullContents = (path as text, optional options as nullable record) as any =>
    let
        contents = Table.Buffer( Folder.Contents(path, options)),
        subfolders = Table.AddColumn(
            Table.SelectRows(contents, each [Attributes][Directory]),
            "File Path",
            each Text.Combine({[Folder Path], [Name]}),
            type text
        )[File Path],
        result = Table.Combine(List.Combine({{contents},
            List.Transform(subfolders, @Folder_FullContents)
        }))
    in result
in Folder_FullContents
```

Comment: Wow, this loaded with _blazing_ speed for OneDrive!  While I haven't validated the actual data, everything looks good so far.  Unfortunately, the opposite seems to be true for the local path, located on an `E:` drive.  Now `E:` does normally take longer than OneDrive, where this spreadsheet itself is located.  After several minutes, however, the query still says `Loading data...`, and has not yet begun to say `xx Rows Loaded`.  I tried `Folder.Contents()` by way of baseline, and _that_ still says `Please wait until we establish a connection to E:\...`, so maybe it's a VPN issue...

Comment: Why would VPN affect a local drive? I have tried this locally on my machine and there are no performance issues so it is probably something else. Don't forget to mark as solved.

Comment: _"Why would VPN affect a local drive?"_  The local `E:\` drive is mapped to a server accessible only by VPN.

Comment: Then it is probably the network slowing things down and nothing to do with PQ.

Comment: I marked it solved!  Interestingly enough, it seems everything on OneDrive is running faster today, so the _buffered_ `Folder_FullContents()` is not truly faster than `Folder.Files()`: they both finish in seconds. However, the original `Folder_FullContents()` was notably _slower_ than `Folder.Files()`, so the equalization is victory enough.

Comment: One further question: I presume `.Buffer()` improves performance by forcibly loading the scalar paths, rather than referencing the queries that yielded those paths? If so, I presume this does _not_ apply to the `[Content]` column, which references `table` objects for folders and `binary` data for files.

Comment: Does this mean that `.Buffer()` would _not_ improve performance for an alternative solution, which obtains the `Folder.Contents()` of the topmost folder, and then recursively expands the folder `table`s from `[Content]`? While the `[Content]` might _look_ fully loaded, I assume the `table`s implicitly reference `.Contents()` queries on their folders, and will only be "lazily loaded" if they are needed?

Comment: PQ normally streams data and sometimes this can be very slow. Table.Buffer just loads the entire table to memory before doing any downstream processing (as long as it is within the same query). There is List.Buffer too.

Comment: I read under [`Table.Buffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-buffer) that only _scalar_ values are loaded.  To pursue my alternative solution, would I need to buffer the `tbl = Table.Buffer(Table.Contents(path, options))`, and then extract and buffer the `[Content]` too, via `List.Buffer(tbl[Content])`?  Or would that still load the `table`s only one level down, rather than recursively?

Comment: Ah, I think you're right. I forgot it was only a shallow buffer. I think it will only ever load one level down.

Comment: Bummer about the shallow buffer.  Is your original solution still good, since we iterate over the scalar `[File Path]`s rather than the objective `[Content]`?  Or since `[File Path]` is a column I added to `contents` via `Table.AddColumn()`, is the buffering still relevant?

Comment: It depends on how many file paths it might encounter. The only way to be sure is to test with and without and you should be able to tell pretty quickly. There is also the recursion aspect which makes things uncertain without explicit testing.